# Azure face verify resource not found

Tags: azure, face-api

I am trying to use the azure face api to verify faces but the below code is giving me a 404 resource not found error. What am I doing wrong? With the same subscription key and endpoint I am able to detect face from url and match it. But my needs are to read image from webcam and match it with a template image.

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

import cv2
import requests

# This key will serve all examples in this document.
KEY = "d06a1f0aae344d7cac11f78eef5abf37"

# This endpoint will be used in all examples in this quickstart.
ENDPOINT = "https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect/"
ENDPOINT_verify = "https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/verify"

# Create an authenticated FaceClient.
face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))
face_client_verify = FaceClient(ENDPOINT_verify, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))

headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':KEY}
headers_verify = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
                  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':KEY}

api_url = ENDPOINT

params = {
    'returnFaceLandmarks':True,
    'returnFaceAttributes':'emotion,age,gender' }

# Base url for the Verify and Facelist/Large Facelist operations
IMAGE_BASE_PATH = 'C:/FaceRecognition/template/'
# Create a list to hold the target photos of the same person
#target_image_file_names = ['Family1-Dad1.jpg', 'Family1-Dad2.jpg']
# The source photos contain this person
source_image_file_name = 'template_viswa.jpg'

local_image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_BASE_PATH + source_image_file_name)
img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', local_image)[1].tobytes()

# Detect face(s) from source image 1, returns a list[DetectedFaces]
# We use detection model 3 to get better performance.
#detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_stream(img)
detected_faces = requests.post(api_url,params=params,headers=headers,data=img)
faceId_source = detected_faces.json()[0]['faceId']
# Add the returned face's face ID
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    imgnew = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)[1].tobytes()
    detected_faces_dest = requests.post(ENDPOINT,params = params,headers=headers,data=imgnew)
    faceId_dest = detected_faces_dest.json()[0]['faceId']
    `face_client_verify.face.verify_face_to_face(faceId_source, faceId_dest)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure face SDK for python to verify faces, the `ENDPOINT_verify` for `FaceClient` should be:

`https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/`

instead of  `https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/verify`

Just try the code below to create a face client for verification:

```
face_client_verify = FaceClient('https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/', CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))
```

Try code blow to have a quick test:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials


ENDPOINT = "https://neurohome-facerecognition.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
Key = "<your key here>"

face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(Key))
face1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url("https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/7A8E/production/_118547313_gettyimages-1174968719.jpg")[0].face_id
face2= face_client.face.detect_with_url("https://images.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2018/05/Bill-gates-770x433.jpg")[0].face_id

result = face_client.face.verify_face_to_face(face1,face2)
print(result.is_identical)
```